# What are equivalent C# data types for SQL Server's date, time and datetimeoffset?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, types

What are the most suitable equivalent C# data types for the date datatypes in SQL Server? I'm specifically looking for

- `date`
- `time`
- `datetimeoffset`

Comment: Since all three answers came through almost simultaneously, they all added-up to a coherent solution.  In retrospect I think I marked the wrong answer as correct, but they're all correct in a way.

I knew the info was on MSDN, but just couldn't find it!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here are the equivalent CLR data types for `date`, `time` and `datetimeoffset` SQL Server data types:

**date** - `DateTime`, `Nullable<DateTime>`
**time** - `TimeSpan`, `Nullable<TimeSpan>`
**datetimeoffset** - `DateTimeOffset`, `Nullable<DateTimeOffset>`

Note that you can find a listing of all SQL Server data types and their CLR equivalents here, [Mapping CLR Parameter Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx)

Comment: TimeSpan is not suitable for SQLs time. The SQL type only holds up to 24h while a .NET TimeSpan includes days, months, years.
See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000) for more details

Answer (score 5):

In C# you could use

- Date
- TimeSpan
- [DateTimeOffset Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(VS.95).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

The new types are supported only if you install .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.

- SqlDbType.Date
- SqlDbType.Time
- SqlDbType.DateTime2
- SqlDbType.DateTimeOffSet

For exhaustive information, see [Date and Time Data in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx)