# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I am trying to output an excel file and part of it puts the value of createddate from a table called outofstock the line is currently putting a 0

If I run this SQL it shows everything fine

```
select wo.email, wo.productid, wo.variantid,  p.NAME pname,  
       p.SKU psku, wo.createdon, pc.CategoryID, c.Name
from woeosemails wo 
join Product p with (nolock) on p.ProductID = wo.productid
left join ProductCategory as pc (nolock) on p.ProductID=pc.ProductID
left join Category as c (nolock) on pc.CategoryID=c.CategoryID
order by wo.createdon, wo.email, wo.productid
```

The problem lies with this line in the aspx.cs file generating the output

```
createdon = DB.RSFieldDateTime(NotifyReader, "createdon");
```

I don't know what type (int, string etc) to place before. Within the SQL table the DataType is datetime but using this does not seem to work.

Any thoughts?

```
string email = DB.RSField(NotifyReader, "email");
int productid = DB.RSFieldInt(NotifyReader, "productid");
int variantid = DB.RSFieldInt(NotifyReader, "variantid");
string createdon = DB.RSFieldDateTime(NotifyReader, "createdon"); 
string psku = DB.RSField(NotifyReader, "psku");
string pname = DB.RSField(NotifyReader, "pname");
string cname = DB.RSField(NotifyReader, "cname");
```

Comment: What happens when you use `DateTime`?

Comment: Is RSFieldDateTime your method, or what is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are equivalent C# data types for SQL Server's date, time and datetimeoffset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655049/what-are-equivalent-c-sharp-data-types-for-sql-servers-date-time-and-datetimeo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the error is clear: you cannot cast a DateTime to string automatically.
You should use

```
DateTime createdon = DB.RSFieldDateTime(NotifyReader, "createdon");
```

or

```
string createdon = DB.RSFieldDateTime(NotifyReader, "createdon").ToString();
```

Also remember that you can use specific formats to represent your date in a string (see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: Also you probably want to use an explicit format there because otherwise it's locale-dependent. It depends a bit on what you want/need to do, but for anything that is not seen by the user an explicit format is probably the best approach.

Comment: Thanks @Јοеу, I was editing my answer to include right that when you posted your comment :)

Comment: Thanks! Been staring at this so long I did not see the To.String(); at the end! Also thanks for that link! Much appreciated