# How to map query result to a class and then a list to then use to populate listview? can't cast query result to class

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2019, dapper

I am trying to populate a listview so I am starting by mapping the result from a query to a class model but it keeps giving me this exception

> System.Data.DataException    Message=Error parsing column 0
> (TimeOfAppointment=15:30:00 - Object)   Source=Dapper
> InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.

my class is

```
public class AppointmentModel
    {
        public string PatientName { get; set; }
        public int AppointmentId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeOfAppointment { get; set; }
        public int Duration { get; set; }
    }
```

my query is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGet_Appointments_byDay]
    @DateSelected date
AS
begin
select [dbo].[Appointments].[TimeOfAppointment], [dbo].[Appointments].[Duration], [dbo].[Patients].[Name], [dbo].[Appointments].[Date], dbo.Appointments.AppointmentId
from [dbo].[Appointments]
inner join [dbo].[Patients] on [dbo].[Appointments].PatientId = [dbo].[Patients].PatientID
where [dbo].[Appointments].[Date] = @DateSelected;
end
```

this is how i call it

```
public List<AppointmentModel> CreateListViewList(DateTime date)
        {
            List<AppointmentModel> ListForListView;
            var l = new DynamicParameters();
            l.Add("@DateSelected", date);
            using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString(db)))
            {
                ListForListView = connection.Query<AppointmentModel>("[Test DB].dbo.spGet_Appointments_byDay", l, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
            }

            return ListForListView;
        }
```

and this is populating the list box

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (IDataConnection db in GlobalConfig.Connections)
            {
                ListForListView.AddRange(db.CreateListViewList(AppointmentDateBox.Value.Date));
            }
            
            foreach (AppointmentModel RowFromQuery in ListForListView)
            {
                ListViewItem viewItem = new ListViewItem(RowFromQuery.TimeOfAppointment.ToString());
                viewItem.SubItems.Add(RowFromQuery.Duration.ToString());
                viewItem.SubItems.Add(RowFromQuery.PatientName);
                viewItem.SubItems.Add(RowFromQuery.AppointmentId.ToString());

                listView1.Items.Add(viewItem);

            }
        }
```

my tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Appointments]
(
    [AppointmentId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [PatientId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL, 
    [Duration] INT NOT NULL, 
    [TimeOfAppointment] TIME NOT NULL, 
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Patients]
(
    [PatientID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [Name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
)
```

I am really new to this so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use TimeSpan in your model for Time data type.

```
//public DateTime TimeOfAppointment { get; set; }

public TimeSpan TimeOfAppointment { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You the below code to solve the issue.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString(db)))
{
    DynamicParameters parameter = new DynamicParameters();
    parameter.Add("@DateSelected", date, DbType.Time, ParameterDirection.Input);

    CommandDefinition cmd = new CommandDefinition("[Test DB].dbo.spGet_Appointments_byDay", parameter, null, null, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    lstLookuptypes = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<List<AppointmentModel>>(cmd).ToList();
}
```

Either you need to change the data type of `TimeOfAppointment`  to `TimeSpan` or you need to change the data type in SQL Server.
Below are the SQL Server and CLR data type mapping.

date - `DateTime`, `Nullable<DateTime>`
time - `TimeSpan`, `Nullable<TimeSpan>`

**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/655070/6527049

Comment: what is "currencycode" ? I tried it with just changing the time datatype to timespan and it worked.

Comment: @Mohammed sorry it was by mistake, I corrected it. It’s advices to use the parameter in the way I have defined